# why can't I perform a union on dual table SparkSQl?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to generate 2 dummy rows in sparks SQL by using "Dual" table,
My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row    
  
df_dual.registerTempTable("dual")
result = sqlContext.sql("select 1,[['Red',['ML', 100.0]],['Green'['Litre', 4.0]]] from dual  
                           union 
                         select 2,[['Red1',['M1L', 100.0]],['Green'['Litre', 4.0]]] from dual ")

result.show()
```

Expected Output :

```
1   [[['Red',['ML', 100.0]],['Green'['Litre', 4.0]]]]
2   [[['Red1',['M1L', 100.0]],['Green'['Litre', 4.0]]]
```

**Error got :**
An error occurred while calling o207.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:

I want to know how to create dummy rows just to experiment few functions using nested data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach looks correct, but I notice some syntactical errors in your `Row` data.

Please check below code that returns your expected output -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row

df_dual = sc.parallelize([Row(r=Row("dummy"))]).toDF()

df_dual.printSchema()
df_dual.show()

df_dual.registerTempTable("dual")


result = sqlContext.sql("select 1 as first_col,(('Red',('ML', 100.0)),('Green',('Litre', 4.0))) as second_col from dual union select 2,(('Red1',('M1L', 100.0)),('Green',('Litre', 4.0))) from dual")


result.show(truncate=False)
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|first_col|second_col                              |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|2        |[[Red1,[M1L,100.0]],[Green,[Litre,4.0]]]|
|1        |[[Red,[ML,100.0]],[Green,[Litre,4.0]]]  |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

However, you really don't need to create `dual` table. You can construct the desired dataframe without `dual` table -

```
result = sqlContext.sql("select 1 as first_col,(('Red',('ML', 100.0)),('Green',('Litre', 4.0))) as second_col union select 2,(('Red1',(
'M1L', 100.0)),('Green',('Litre', 4.0)))")

result.show(truncate=False)
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|first_col|second_col                              |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
|2        |[[Red1,[M1L,100.0]],[Green,[Litre,4.0]]]|
|1        |[[Red,[ML,100.0]],[Green,[Litre,4.0]]]  |
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```